# ReactJS - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the error when I'm using '?'. What should i use instead?

**The error is:**

Module parse failed: Unexpected token You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

```
const accessToken = user?.accessToken
   if(accessToken){
      const decodedAccessToken = decode(accessToken)
      if(decodedAccessToken.exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()){
         console.log(decodedAccessToken.exp);
         renewAccessToken(user.user._id)
       }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get error also if you put user?.accessToken directly inside first if brackets instead of using const before?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. We have to use like this:

```
const accessToken =  user ? user.accessToken : null;
```

Comment: have you found out why the original syntax didn't work in your case? I'm having the same issue.